# Recibir 2 datos o mas por AJAX con SELECT

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Lo que quiero es poder seleccionar las dos opciones de los combo (`MES` y `ANO`) y que por medio de la función `onChange` me muestre los datos del gráfico, aclaro que con un solo dato(MES) me muestra los resultados, pero no se como hacerlo con dos variables.

```
<div class="caja">
<select name="ANO" id="ANO">
    <option>Seleccione...</option>
    <option>2014</option>
    <option>2016</option>
    <option>2015</option>
    <option>2017</option>
    <option>2018</option>
  </select>
</div>
<br>
<div class="caja">
    <select name="MES" id="MES" onChange="mostrarResultados(this.value)">
        <option>Seleccione...</option>
        <option value="1">ENERO</option>
        <option value="2">FEBRERO</option>
        <option value="3">MARZO</option>
        <option value="4">ABRIL</option>
        <option value="5">MAYO</option>
        <option value="6">JUNIO</option>
        <option value="7">JULIO</option>
        <option value="8">AGOSTO</option>
        <option value="9">SEPTIEMBRE</option>
        <option value="10">OCTUBRE</option>
        <option value="11">NOVIEMBRE</option>
        <option value="12">DICIEMBRE</option>
    </select>
</div>
    <div class="resultados"><canvas id="grafico"></canvas></div>
</body>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$MES = $_POST['MES'];
$ANO = $_POST['ANO'];
?>
```

**JQUERY**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(mostrarResultados(2015));  
            function mostrarResultados(MES){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'controlador/procesar.php',
                    data:'MES='+ MES,
                    success:function(data){

                        var valores = eval(data);

                        var dia1 = valores[0];
                        var dia2 = valores[1];
                        var dia3 = valores[2];
                        var dia4 = valores[3];
                        var dia5 = valores[4];
                        var dia6 = valores[5];
                        //Continua


                        var Datos = {
                                labels : ['DIA_1', 'DIA_2', 'DIA_3', 'DIA_4', 'DIA_5', 'DIA_6'],
                                datasets : [
                                    {
                                        fillColor : 'rgba(91,228,146,0.6)', 
                                        strokeColor : 
                                        highlightFill : 
                                        highlightStroke : 
                                        data : [dia1, dia2, dia3, dia4, 
dia5, dia6, dia7, dia8, dia9, dia10, dia11, dia12, dia13, dia14, dia15, 
dia16, dia17, dia18, dia19, dia20, dia21, dia22, dia23, dia24, dia25, dia26, 
dia27, dia28, dia29, dia30, dia31]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }

                        var contexto = 
document.getElementById('grafico').getContext('2d');
                        window.Barra = new Chart(contexto).Bar(Datos, { 
responsive : true });
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
</script>
```

Comment: Tienes que pasar ambos valores en la petición Ajax, cambiando esto: `data:'MES='+ MES` por esto: `data:{'MES': MES, 'ANO:'ANO}` el código jQuery puede ser lanzando desde un botón o en el on change de cualquiera de los select, y debes recuperar (mejor en jQuery)  los valores `MES` y `ANO` seleccionados actualmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Envia los parametros en notacion json especificandole el nombre de los mismos:

```
var _mes = $("#MES").val();
var _ano = $("#ANO").val();
 $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'controlador/procesar.php',
    data: { MES : _mes , ANO : _ano }
    //...
```

Answer (score 0):

Y si le sacas el document ready y en el onchange ejecutas la funcion mostrarResultados().

```
function mostrarResultados(){
    var mesSelect=document.getelementsById('MES').value;
    var anoSelect=document.getelementsById('ANO').value;
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'controlador/procesar.php',
                    data:{MES:mesSelect, ANO:anoSelect},
                    success:function(data){
```